# iOS: Can't start cordova inAppBrowser -> "Warning: Attempt to present <inAppBrowser> on <MainViewController> while a presentation is in progress"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, inappbrowser

I really need some help, because I'm very new to iOS and Phonegap developing and all topics on my Xcode-warning I could find were about Objective-C.

As my app is mainly written with Cordova (Phonegap) these solutions aren't really helpful.

So, what is there to tell:

I have a simple start screen, where you can start a barcode-scanner. The result (which in the end is always an url) should be displayed in the inAppBrowser of cordova.

If I call the `window.open()` with "_self" it works, but then it is very difficult to get back to the startscreen, as far as I found out.
So I wanted to call the url with the inAppBrowser so there is a "Done" button, but Xcode screams:

> "Warning: Attempt to present <CDVInAppBrowserViewController:
>   0x1ed97060> on <MainViewController: 0x1ed64730> while a presentation
>   is in progress!"

Here the JavaScript code where I'm calling the window.open() function...

```
app.initialize();

function demoScan() {
  try {
    var scanned = scan();
  } catch (e) {
    alert('scan failed');
  }
}

function scan() {
   var scanner = window.cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");
   scanner.scan(  function (result) {
      var ref = window.open(encodeURI(result.text),'_blank','location=yes');
        },
        function (error) {
          ("Scanning failed: " + error);
      });
   }
```

In the end, I only need a (simple) solution, to get back to the start page "index.html" when I'm on the Webpage the Barcode scanner is calling. If it is through the inAppBrowser or with a self-coded "back" button in the WebView, I really don't care.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. You have to set a timeout before calling the inAppBrowser:

```
setTimeout( function() { 
               var ref = window.open(encodeURI(result.text),'_blank','location=no');
            }, 500);
```

Apparently iOS needs some time to end whatever it was doing, before it can start the inAppBrowser.
In Android it works without the timeout.